# sphinx documentation exclude a baseclass from :inherited-members:

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm documenting some Python code that has multiple layers of inheritance using Sphinx.  The structure is roughly:

```py
class _foo(np.ndarray):
    #do _foo stuff

class bar(_foo):
    #do bar stuff

class baz(_foo):
    #do baz stuff
```

With :inherited-members: in my .rst file I get the documentation from `_foo` as part of `bar` and `baz` but I also get all the documentation from `np.ndarray`, which I don't want.

The Sphinx documentation (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html) says:

> For example; If your class Foo is derived from list class and you don’t want to document list.__len__(), you should specify a option *:inherited-members: list* to avoid special members of list class.

But I've tried:

- :inherited-members: np.ndarray
- :inherited-members: ndarray
- :inherited-members: numpy.ndarray

None of which prevent the entirety of numpy.ndarray documentation being included for every single class.  Does anyone know if there's a way to exclude the numpy documentation, but keep the parts I need?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that this feature is new in Sphinx 3.0 so... you need Sphinx 3.0 in order to filter `:inherited-members:` by superclass. Also provide a working reproduction case, because I can't even get sphinx 3 to add `np.ndarray`'s documentation to `bar` in a local project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in comments by @Masklinn, requires version 3.0 or higher, it then works correctly with:

```
:inherited-members: ndarray
```